# Monitor temperature in fahrenheit

Tags: temperature

Using raspbian right now. I know you can add the temperature plugin to the panel, but it only shows Celsius. How can this be changed? Or is there another program I can use that will work better?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default [desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) (DE) on raspbian is LXDE.  If you search online ([**e.g.**](http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=36245)) with regard to this issue, you'll find a chorus of crickets -- meaning no one cares that much.  If this is very important to you, you could figure out exactly where the widget comes from and try and contact who's responsible, although I would guess by this point they are aware and do not care either.

There are other GUI temperature monitors available that are configurable this way (both [conky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conky_%28software%29) and [gkrellm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GKrellM), I believe).  There are also completely different desktop environments available for the pi, although I cannot promise they come with sensor widgets that have a Fahrenheit option.

Comment: These worked. gkrellm was the prettier out of the two.

Comment: I like gkrellm; it's been around a long time.  Raspbian has some plugins for it if you search `apt-cache search gkrellm` -- `gkrellmtop` is handy.  There's hundreds of skins for it ([see here](http://www.muhri.net/gkrellm/); you can download the tarball and just unpack it in `~/.gkrellm/themes`).   If you like things that look fancy, the [sunlight plugin](http://fzort.org/mpr/projects/gkrellsunlight/) is cool.